# lifecycle: when do I hide and show tab bar in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

To hide my tab bar I do

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
}
```

So clearly to make it show again, all I need to do is call

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=NO;
```

But in which lifecycle method should I make this call? There seems to be disagreement on which lifecycle methods are still valid in the latest iOS/Xcode. Also, as a matter of sound engineering, I would like to know the very correct answer: `viewDidDisappear` or `ViewDidUnload` or `ViewDidDispose`?

Comment: The reason I have to show the tabs again is because once one ViewController calls `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;`, the view is hidden forever. So instead of going through every view controller to show it, I have the controller responsible for hiding it to show it back when it's leaving the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Answer your question from apple doc

> viewDidUnload [...] Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged
>   under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.

So `viewDidUnload` is deprecated in iOS 6.0 and the best place to put `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=NO;` is in `viewDidDisappear` but as `viewDidDisappear` call when view removed from screen not from memory it can be any case.So if view appear again it will not call `viewDidLoad` so in this case `tabbar` will remain unhidden and to solve that you need to do two things.
Put `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;` in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewWillLoad` and

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
}
```

and put unhidden call of tabbar to `viewDidDisappear`

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=NO;
}
```

It will manage all cases and other places are not safe to put this call.You should always work with `viewWill/DidAppear` and `viewDid/WillDisappear` and also `viewWillLoad` in some cases as they are safe and always call if there is not an uncertain condition(crash etc).

Comment: viewDidDisappear didn't fix it. The bar still stays gone forever. (and I just copied and pasted your code)

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you want to achieve, there is a more elegant solution für many use cases:

**StoryBoard:**

Go to the view controller you want to push.

check "Hide Bottom Bar on Push"

**Programmatically:**

In the pushed viewController:

```
override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
    set {
        super.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = newValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, but it depends on when you want it to be hidden. Also, to unhide it you should use `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=NO;` (note the `NO` instead of `YES`).

If I'd guess the effect you're trying to achieve, I'd tell you to implement it in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`.